# sorting a string with the following conditions

Tags: python

A string s1 contains alphanumeric characters only. I have to sort the string with the following condition:

->All sorted lowercase letters are ahead of uppercase letters.

->All sorted uppercase letters are ahead of digits.

->All sorted odd digits are ahead of sorted even digits.

eg. **Sorting1234 -> ginortS1324**

**code:**

```py
l,u,o,e=[],[],[],[]
for i in sorted(input()):
    if i.isalpha():
        x = u if i.isupper() else l
    else:
        x = o if int(i)%2 else e
    x.append(i)
print("".join(l+u+o+e))
```

can anyone help understand this code?

is there any easier way to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have explained each step below. Open this in a code editor. It will make it easier to read.**

```
l,u,o,e=[],[],[],[] #define lower, upper, odd and even number lists.
for i in sorted(input()): #split the characters so string looks like [s,t,r,i,n,g]
    if i.isalpha(): #check if i is a letter
        x = u if i.isupper() else l #add x to upper list if it is an upper, if not, add it to l or the lower list. You can see `ternary operator` for more info. 
    else: #if it is not a letter
        x = o if int(i)%2 else e # if the integer is even add it to e, if it is odd, add it to odd.
    x.append(i)
print("".join(l+u+o+e)) #join all the sorted letters in their respective order.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def key_function(character):
    return (character.isdigit() - character.islower(), character in "02468", character)


input_string = "Sorting1234"

print(*sorted(input_string, key=key_function), sep="")
```

One-Liner:

```
print(
    *sorted(input_string, key=lambda x: (x.isdigit() - x.islower(), x in "02468", x)),
    sep=""
)
```

Output:

```
ginortS1324
```

Answer (score 1):

This code seems like a very simple way to achieve this. It is creating 4 lists at the begenning for lowercase (`l`), uppercase (`u`), odd (`o`), and even (`e`) characters. Then it is iterating through a string provided by the user.

These are the same things:

```
string = input()
for character in string:
   ...
```

and

```
for character in input():
   ...
```

They put the `sorted(input())` there to make sure the numbers and characters are sorted in alphabetical order.

Then, they are checking whether the current character is a letter (`.isalpha()`) and if it is, check if the letter is upper case or lower case (`i.isupper()`).

If the character is numeric, they are checking if it is even (`i%2`). The `%` is called Modulus and gives the remainder of a division. So if an even number is divided by 2, the remainder is 0 (False) and if it's an odd number, it is 1 (True).

Based on this, they are setting the list to which this character has to be added (`l, u, o, or e`) to `x`.

Finally, they are appending the character to that particular list and adding all the elements together.